# What exactly does this do?

Tags: javascript

Hello all I have seen code like the following:

```
userFunc.apply.bind(userFunc, userFunc)
```

where `userFunc` is a function. I don't understand why the first & second arguments to `bind` are the function itself. What problem does this solve? Isn't the second argument meant for the arguments?

Source code is [here](https://github.com/developit/greenlet/blob/master/greenlet.js#L17).

Comment: The second argument probably should be something else than `userFunc`.

Comment: Where have you seen this code?

Comment: `this` is a reference to the scope, because if the callback is called from the function, the scope will be lost. Also, it can be written this way: `userFunc.apply(() => userFunc())`. Also there are lots of similar questions here on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method

Comment: @XanderLuciano No, `userFunc.apply(() => userFunc())` does something really different than `userFunc.apply.bind(userFunc, userFunc)`

Comment: This is not a duplicate guys! @Bergi . I understand its similar, but why this special use case is my question.

Comment: @batman The exact same [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39907146/1048572) applies. Notice that `userFunc.apply === Function.prototype.apply === Function.apply`, and that the second argument really should have been `null` (or anything else, but not the function itself) as my first comment indicated

Comment: @batman Even the use case, as a promise callback, is exactly the same :-)

Comment: @Bergi. I have given the source code link stating the second argument is not `null` but rather its own `function`

Comment: @batman Yes, but it does not affect how `apply.bind` works - and ultimately the value is ignored anyway (it's the `this` inside `userFunc`). If you understand what it does, you will see that passing `null` makes more sense than passing `userFunc`.

Comment: @Bergi I just looked at the linked duplicate question and see my mistake. Thanks for the correction. Should have done a little more research before commenting, but better to have to been wrong and learned something, that to have not said anything and be ignorant. Thanks for the correction!